# f(0)>g(0) and $f'(t)\ge g'(t)$ then set of f(x)=g(x) lies in

Tags: calculus

Let f and g be differentiable functions on the real line R with f(0)>g(0). Assume that the set M={ t$\in R : f(t)=g(t)$} is non-empty and that $f'(t)\ge g'(t)$ for all t $\in$ M, then which of the following is necessarily true?

(a) if t $\in$ M then t<0

(b) for any t $\in$ M, $f'(t)> g'(t)$

(C) for any t $\notin$ M, $f(t)> g(t)$

(d) None of the above

My approach is when t>0, f(t) will always be above g(t) except at points in M, but for t<0 f(x) may be less than g(x), which eliminates a and c. And from graph it is possible to eliminate (b). I want to ensure that answer is D or I am missing something

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: Sorry, only d is true. I did not read the question carefully.

Comment: Your arguments are valid but you probably should include examples showing thar a,  b , c  are not true.

Comment: I plan to do that using graphs

Comment: Graphs alone are not enough to show that the functions are differentiable.